# R data.table remove rows where one column is duplicated if another column is NA

Tags: r, data.table

Here is an example data.table

```
dt <- data.table(col1 = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D'), col2 = c(NA, 'dog', 'cat', 'jeep', 'porsch', NA))

   col1   col2
1:    A     NA
2:    A    dog
3:    B    cat
4:    C   jeep
5:    C porsch
6:    D     NA
```

I want to remove rows where col1 is duplicated if col2 is NA and has a non-NA value in another row. AKA group by col1, then if group has more than one row and one of them is NA, remove it. This would be the result for `dt`:

```
   col1   col2
2:    A    dog
3:    B    cat
4:    C   jeep
5:    C porsch
6:    D     NA
```

I tried this:

```
dt[, list(col2 = ifelse(length(col1>1), col2[!is.na(col2)], col2)), by=col1]

   col1 col2
1:    A  dog
2:    B  cat
3:    C jeep
4:    D   NA
```

What am I missing? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An attempt to find all the `NA` cases in groups where there is also a non-`NA` value, and then remove those rows:

```
dt[-dt[, .I[any(!is.na(col2)) & is.na(col2)], by=col1]$V1]
#   col1   col2
#1:    A    dog
#2:    B    cat
#3:    C   jeep
#4:    C porsch
#5:    D     NA
```

Seems quicker, though I'm sure someone is going to turn up with an even quicker version shortly:

```
set.seed(1)
dt2 <- data.table(col1=sample(1:5e5,5e6,replace=TRUE), col2=sample(c(1:8,NA),5e6,replace=TRUE))
system.time(dt2[-dt2[, .I[any(!is.na(col2)) & is.na(col2)], by=col1]$V1])
#   user  system elapsed 
#   1.49    0.02    1.51 
system.time(dt2[, .(col2 = if(all(is.na(col2))) NA_integer_ else na.omit(col2)), by = col1])
#   user  system elapsed 
#   4.49    0.04    4.54
```

Answer (score 4):

> group by col1, then if group has more than one row and one of them is NA, remove it.

Use an anti-join:

```
dt[!dt[, if (.N > 1L) .SD[NA_integer_], by=col1], on=names(dt)]

   col1   col2
1:    A    dog
2:    B    cat
3:    C   jeep
4:    C porsch
5:    D     NA
```

Benchmark from @thela, but assuming there are no (full) dupes in the original data:

```
set.seed(1)
dt2a <- data.table(col1=sample(1:5e5,5e6,replace=TRUE), col2=sample(c(1:8,NA),5e6,replace=TRUE))
dt2 = unique(dt2a)

system.time(res_thela <- dt2[-dt2[, .I[any(!is.na(col2)) & is.na(col2)], by=col1]$V1])
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.73    0.06    0.81

system.time(res_psidom <- dt2[, .(col2 = if(all(is.na(col2))) NA_integer_ else na.omit(col2)), by = col1])
#    user  system elapsed 
#    2.86    0.03    2.89 

system.time(res <- dt2[!dt2[, .N, by=col1][N > 1L, !"N"][, col2 := dt2$col2[NA_integer_]], on=names(dt2)])
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.39    0.01    0.41 

fsetequal(res, res_thela) # TRUE
fsetequal(res, res_psidom) # TRUE
```

I changed a little for speed. With [a `having=` argument](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/788), this might become faster and more legible.

Answer (score 3):

You missed the parenthesis (maybe a typo), I suppose it should be `length(col1) > 1`; And also used `ifelse` on a scalar condition which will not work as you expect it to (only the first element from the vector is picked up); If you want to remove NA values from a group when there are non NAs, you can use `if/else`:

```
dt[, .(col2 = if(all(is.na(col2))) NA_character_ else na.omit(col2)), by = col1]

#   col1   col2
#1:    A    dog
#2:    B    cat
#3:    C   jeep
#4:    C porsch
#5:    D     NA
```