# How to keep one instance or more of the values in one column when removing duplicate rows?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to remove rows with duplicate values in one column of a data frame. I want to make sure that all the existing values in that column are represented, appearing more than once if its values in one other column are not duplicated and non-missing, and only once if the values in that other column are all missing. Take for example the following data frame:

```
toy <- data.frame(Group = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,6,7,7), Class = c("a",NA,"a","b",NA,NA,NA,NA,"a","b","a","a","a"))
```

I would like to end up with this:

```
ideal <- data.frame(Group = c(1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6,7), Class = c("a","a","b",NA,NA,"a","b","a","a"))
```

I tried transforming the data frame into a data table and follow the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45557011/r-data-table-remove-rows-where-one-column-is-duplicated-if-another-column-is-na), like this:

```
library(data.table)
toy.dt <- as.data.table(toy)
toy.dt[, .(Class = if(all(is.na(Class))) NA_character_ else na.omit(Class)), by = Group]
```

but duplicates weren't handled as needed: value 7 in the column 'Group' should appear only once in the resulting data.

It would be a bonus if the solution doesn't require transforming the data into a data table.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using base R. We first drop `NA` rows in `toy` and select only unique rows. We can then left join it with unique `Group` values to get the rows which are `NA` for the `group`.

```
df1 <- unique(na.omit(toy))
merge(unique(subset(toy, select = Group)), df1, all.x = TRUE)


#  Group Class
#1     1     a
#2     2     a
#3     2     b
#4     3  <NA>
#5     4  <NA>
#6     5     a
#7     5     b
#8     6     a
#9     7     a
```

---

Same logic using `dplyr` functions :

```
library(dplyr)
toy %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  distinct() %>%
  right_join(toy %>% distinct(Group))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to try a `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(tidyverse)

toy %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  filter(!(is.na(Class) & sum(!is.na(Class)) > 0)) %>%
  distinct()
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 9 x 2
# Groups:   Group [7]
  Group Class
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 a    
2     2 a    
3     2 b    
4     3 NA   
5     4 NA   
6     5 a    
7     5 b    
8     6 a    
9     7 a
```