# Removing duplicates if there is NA in one of the duplicates in R

Tags: r, duplicates

I am trying to remove duplicates from a dataset (caused by merging). However, one row contains a value and one does not, in some cases both rows are NA. I want to keep the ones with data, and if there are on NAs, then it does not matter which I keep. How do I do that? I am stuck.

I unsuccessfully tried the solutions from here (also not usually working with data.table, so I dont understand whats what)

[R data.table remove rows where one column is duplicated if another column is NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45557011/r-data-table-remove-rows-where-one-column-is-duplicated-if-another-column-is-na)

Some minimum example data:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "E", "G", "H", "J", "J"),
                 value = c(NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L))

ID value
A    NA
A     1
B    NA
B    NA
C     1
D     1
E     1
G     1
H     1
J    NA
J     1
```

and I want this:

```
ID value
A     1
B    NA
C     1
D     1
E     1
G     1
H     1
J     1
```

Comment: Also the answer from @Psidom in the linked question would work, you only need to adapt for integer: `library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(value = if (all(is.na(value))) NA_integer_ else na.omit(value)), by = ID]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possibility using `dplyr` could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 slice(which.max(!is.na(value)))

  ID    value
  <chr> <int>
1 A         1
2 B        NA
3 C         1
4 D         1
5 E         1
6 G         1
7 H         1
8 J         1
```

Comment: This was slightly faster than @Darren Tsais solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a relatively simple `data.table` solution.

Grouping by `ID` if all the values are `NA` just take the first `value`, if not take all values that are not `NA`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, if (all(is.na(value))) value[1] else value[!is.na(value)], by = ID]
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Sometimes it helps already to know how to properly read the code.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative of @tmfmnk's answer with `slice_max()` in `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice_max(!is.na(value), with_ties = F)

# # A tibble: 8 x 2
# # Groups:   ID [8]
#   ID    value
#   <chr> <int>
# 1 A         1
# 2 B        NA
# 3 C         1
# 4 D         1
# 5 E         1
# 6 G         1
# 7 H         1
# 8 J         1
```